# How can 'no zero argument constructor' be avoided?

Tags: java, android

An activity that retrieves and displays data from a database failed to instantiate because there is no zero argument constructor - why is it important to include it?

Here is the activity (I'm quite new to this so there will be parts where it could have been executed better...open to suggestions!)

```
package com.example.createrecipefinal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class preview_recipe extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private TextView viewRecipeName, viewCountry, viewTime, viewTxtEquipment, viewTxtIngredients, viewTxtMethod, viewPersonalStory;

    public preview_recipe(DBHelper dbHelper) {
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview_recipe);

        viewRecipeName = findViewById(R.id.viewRecipeName);
        viewCountry = findViewById(R.id.viewCountry);
        viewTime = findViewById(R.id.viewTime);
        viewTxtEquipment = findViewById(R.id.viewTxtEquipment);
        viewTxtMethod = findViewById(R.id.viewTxtMethod);
        viewPersonalStory = findViewById(R.id.viewPersonalStory);
        viewTxtIngredients = findViewById(R.id.viewTxtIngredients);

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(preview_recipe.this);
        //call read function and array
        List<RecipeModel> returnRecipe = dbHelper.readRecipe();

        //Setting values into text views
        viewRecipeName.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(1));
        viewCountry.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(2));
        viewTxtEquipment.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(5));
        viewTxtIngredients.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(6));
        viewTxtMethod.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(7));
        viewPersonalStory.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(8));
    }

}

2022-04-04 19:37:05.963 14815-14815/com.example.createrecipefinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.createrecipefinal, PID: 14815
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.createrecipefinal/com.example.createrecipefinal.preview_recipe}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.createrecipefinal.preview_recipe> has no zero argument constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3591)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: Be aware that you should **never** be calling an Activity constructor to create it yourself either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero argument constructor is required because the android runtime doesn't know how to create the object (`DBHelper dbHelper`) that your constructor requires.

The `dbHelper` that your constructor requires as useless anyway (you create a `new DBHelper(preview_recipe.this)` in `onCreate()`), so the solution is to remove this useless parameter:

```
public class preview_recipe extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView viewRecipeName, viewCountry, viewTime, viewTxtEquipment, viewTxtIngredients, viewTxtMethod, viewPersonalStory;

    public preview_recipe() {
    }

    //... remainder of the code
}
```

Please also note that in Java (and Android) it is the convention to write class names in CamelCase (like the `AppCompatActivity`), so your class should be named:

```
public class PreviewRecipe extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView viewRecipeName, viewCountry, viewTime, viewTxtEquipment, viewTxtIngredients, viewTxtMethod, viewPersonalStory;

    public PreviewRecipe() {
    }

    //... remainder of the code
}
```